# Query about optical absorption spectra

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, optical-properties

I have one query about data obtained in the optical calculation (absorption coefficient) using GGA. The output came in the format energy xx yy zz xy yz zx for bulk system. I have seen in the literature while showing for absorption coefficient, only two components E||a, and E||c have been shown. In my case, how I can decide which component is a or c. I potted xx yy and zz components separately. All three show different absorption peaks. Please suggest the correct way of representing it. I am not aware of the format obtained in the output.
Please see Fig.6 in the attached reference.
https://www.nature.com/articles/srep07131

Comment: E || a should be xx, E || c should be zz. The equivalent of yy should be E || b.

Comment: @AndreyPoletayev Thank you so much for clarifying my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an answer that was satisfactory to the OP was written in a [comment by Andrey Poletayev](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9761/query-about-optical-absorption-spectra#comment20589_9761):

> "E || a should be xx, E || c should be zz. The equivalent of yy should be E || b."

This Community Wiki post can be deleted if someone wants to write a more detailed answer.